# Tensorflow running slower than Benchmarks?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, neural-network

So I'm just experimenting with an average AlexNet. I have the ImageNet data processed as in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception, and I am loading as such:

```
G = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=G,
                                config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))


train_dataset = ImagenetData('train')

train_images, train_labels = image_processing.distorted_inputs(train_dataset)

if mode == 'local':
    label_batch = tf.one_hot(train_labels,k)
elif mode =='sherlock':
    label_batch = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(train_labels,k,1,0),tf.float32)



AlexNet = ConvNet(G,'AlexNet',session=sess,X =image_batch,y = label_batch,k=k,H=H,W=W,D=D,mode='sherlock')
AlexNet.session.run(tf.Print([1], [1], str(LR)))
AlexNet.session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())


with tf.device('/gpu:0'):

    [..Build AlexNet here...]

    AlexNet.finalizeBuild()



coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
AlexNet.session.run(tf.Print([1], [1], 'coordinator made'))
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=AlexNet.session,coord=coord)


val_accs = []
losses = [] 

for itt in range(nitt):

    AlexNet.session.run(tf.Print([1], [1], str(itt)))


    AlexNet.session.run(train_step)
```

Each batch takes about 15 seconds to run.... When I look at the benchmarks (https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks/blob/master/README.md) for similar GPUs, I see that they take only 81 ms per batch. Is there something I'm doing dreadfully wrong here?

Comment: You can try to get timeline of the slow session.run call to see where you are spending the time -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the advice! So, it turns out that it was the LocalResponseNorm layer. The forward/backward pass to this was taking about 8 seconds per batch on its own. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Which version of TF? LRN was CPU-only before 35df3ed. Also doing batch-normalization renders LRN unnecessary and is faster than LRN (tf 0.12 introduced fast fused version of batch norm)

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense... Currently stuck 0.9 with a GPU.